# how to map objects into arrays in a query

Tags: arangodb

Let's suppose I have a collection named "repos" containing objects like this one:

```js
{
  name: 'myrepo',
  actions: [
     { timestamp: '2016-04-12T14:43:20Z', change: 'add' },
     { timestamp: '2016-04-12T14:45:10Z', change: 'remove' },
     { timestamp: '2016-04-12T15:03:03Z', change: 'add' },
     ... and so on ....
  ]
}
```

Now I want a query to convert each of these objects into something like this:

```js
{
   name: 'myrepo',
   timestamps: ['2016-04-12T14:43:20Z', '2016-04-12T14:45:10Z', '2016-04-12T15:03:03Z'],
   changes: ['add', 'remove', 'add']
}
```

I have thought of something like the following:

```
FOR r in repos
LET changes= (FOR a IN r.actions RETURN a.change )
LET timestamps = (FOR a IN r.actions RETURN a.timestamp)
RETURN {
    name: r.name,
    changes: changes,
    timestamps: timestamps
    }
```

but I am afraid that the double FOR may be not very efficient.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express your query in a more compact form using the [array expansion operator](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Aql/ArrayOperators.html):

```
FOR r IN repos RETURN {
  name: r.name,
  changes: r.actions[*].change,
  timestamps: r.actions[*].timestamp
}
```

You may also use `UNIQUE` to only get every change type once per record in your result (if the arrays `changes` and `timestamps` don't have to lineup):

```
FOR r IN repos RETURN {
    name: r.name,
    changes: UNIQUE(r.actions[*].change),
    timestamps: r.actions[*].timestamp
}
```

In general, your query only adds the overhead of two sub-queries, and shouldn't be that much slower than the above. However, it's more compact and therefore a little bit better to read, isn't it?